# Check if there are sufficient attributes in each table row

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

TransactionListPage.transactionTableRows.should('be.visible').and('have.length.greaterThan', 0);

I located table rows and checked if table got at least 1 row and now trying to achieve the following

1. each raw in a table got attributes and i would like to check if attributes are present in all rows , how can i do that ?  i assume i have to iterate over each element and check if element certain attribute is present and not empty

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmmh6.png)

Comment: What is the attribute are you looking for that should be present in all rows?

Comment: you see on the screenshot every column in the row have some value either its BTC or something else i want to check if every column consist of some value not exact but some

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have to loop over all `td` elements and then assert that a particular attribute is present in all td elements, then you can do like this:

```js
cy.get('tbody[role="rowgroup"] tr td').each(($ele) => {
  cy.wrap($ele).should('have.attr', 'role')
})
```

If you want to check that the `role` attribute has the value `cell` for all `td` elements, you can do:

```js
cy.get('tbody[role="rowgroup"] tr td').each(($ele) => {
  cy.wrap($ele).should('have.attr', 'role', 'cell')
})
```

To check that every `td` element has some innerText like BTC etc., you can do like this. Here we are checking the length of text after removing all the spaces to be atleast 1, so this will check that there is a valid inner text present.

```js
cy.get('tbody[role="rowgroup"] tr td').each(($ele) => {
  expect($ele.text().trim().length).to.be.at.least(1)
})
```

Comment: thank you thats clear sorry i wasnt clear at first, i want to check if each column have some value  that is not empty is that possible at all?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Actually the thing you are looking for is inner text and not value, that got me confused a bit.

Comment: i ams sorry and thank you for your help , healped me a lot

Comment: Alapan you mind opening chat ?

Comment: i figure out that not everything column have a value so i would like to specifically point or exclude one is that possible, all the columns have value except (fee) value ine very row